# Smallest epsilon so that comparison result change

Tags: java, floating-point, comparison

What is the smallest float value A so that `(x < x + A) == true`?

I tried with Float.MIN_VALUE but surprisingly(? [1]) it doesn't work (except for values of 0.)

Knowing how the IEEE 754 standard stores float values, I could just add 1 to the mantissa of the float in question, but this seams really hackish. I don't want to put byte arrays and bit operations in my code for such a trivial matter, especially with Java. In addition if I simply add 1 to the Float.floatToIntBits() and the mantissa is all 1, it will increase the exponent  by 1 and set the mantissa to 0. I don't want to implements all the handling of this cases if it is not necessary.

Isn't there some sort of function (hopefully build-in) that given the float x, it returns the smallest float A such that `(x < x + A) == true`?
If there isn't, what would be the cleanest way to implement it?

I'm using this because of how I'm iterating over a line of vertices

```
// return the next vertices strictly at the left of pNewX
float otherLeftX = pOppositeToCurrentCave.leftVertexTo(pNewX);
// we add MIN_VALUE so that the next call to leftVertexTo will return the same vertex returned by leftVertexTo(pNewX)
otherLeftX += Float.MIN_VALUE;
while(otherLeftX >= 0 && pOppositeToCurrentCave.hasLeftVertexTo(otherLeftX)) {
    otherLeftX = pOppositeToCurrentCave.leftVertexTo(otherLeftX);
    //stuff
}
```

Right now because of this problem the first vertex is always skipped because the second call to `leftVertexTo(otherLeftX)` doesn't return the same value it returned on the first call

[1] Not so surprising. I happened to realize after I noticed the problem that since the gap between floats is relative, for whatever number != 0 the MIN_VALUE is so small that it will be truncated and `(x = x + FLOAT.MIN_VALUE) == true`

Comment: There is no one answer; the answer depends on `x`.  If `x` is a `double` between `2^n` and `2^(n+1)`, then the smallest float `A` is `2^(n-51)` (or maybe `n-52`); this depends on the magnitude of `x`.  I think the classic way to check to make sure `x` and `y` are close enough to equal is `(abs(x-y)/abs(x)) < EPSILON`; the last time I tried this, EPSILON was `1e-15`, and my program got into infinite loops if I made it smaller than that.  This is for a `double`.  For a `float` EPSILON needs to be larger (`1e-6`?).

Comment: I know that this depends on X. To quote myself "Isn't there some sort of function (hopefully build-in) that given the float x, it returns the smallest float A such that (x < x + A) == true?". Note that I'm doing a less then comparison, not an equality comparison. The problem can be see as "what is the gap between x and its successor?"

Comment: The step size to the next representable value is **not** the same as the smallest `A` such that `x < x+A`. If `x+u` is the next representable value after `x`, then `A` is near `u/2`, because `x+u/2` is between two values and must be rounded to one of them. If the low bit of the significand of x is odd, then `A` is exactly `u/2`, because `x+u/2` will be rounded up. If the low bit is even, then `A` is `u/2` plus **its** step to the next representable value (because rounding of the exact midpoint would be downward, so we must add slightly more than half).

Comment: You are right, I didn't thought of it. Nice addition :) On the other hand, given the sample code I provided, we can see that there would be no difference if we use u or u/2 or nextUp(u/2), since the rounding happens before the assignment. Thank you anyways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `Math.nextUp(x)`

Here is the doc:

> Returns the floating-point value adjacent to f in the direction of positive infinity. This method is semantically equivalent to nextAfter(f, Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY); however, a nextUp implementation may run faster than its equivalent nextAfter call.
>
> Special Cases:
>
> ```
>    If the argument is NaN, the result is NaN.
>    If the argument is positive infinity, the result is positive infinity.
>    If the argument is zero, the result is Float.MIN_VALUE
> ```
>
> Parameters:
>
> ```
>    f - starting floating-point value
> ```
>
> Returns:
>
> ```
>    The adjacent floating-point value closer to positive infinity.
> ```

Comment: Definitely what I was looking for! I actually put the idea you used in the comments to my question, but I did not know of Math.nextUp. Thanks